# How to access a variable from one viewController's method body to another ViewController

Tags: objective-c

Below is my code:

SecondViewController.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,  UINavigationControllerDelegate> 
-(IBAction) UploadMethod:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger numberOfImagesUploaded ;
@end
```

SecondViewController.m :

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
@interface SecondViewController ()
@end

@implementation SecondViewController
@synthesize numberOfImagesUploaded ;

NSInteger numberOfImagesUploaded = 1 ;
-(IBAction)UploadMethod:(id)sender {
    // Upload method (not important)

    numberOfImagesUploaded ++ ;
}
```

ThirdViewController.m :

```
#import "ThirdViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"
@interface ThirdViewController () 
@end
@implementation ThirdViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    SecondViewController *useSecondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil] ;
    NSInteger number = useSecondView.numberOfImagesUploaded ;
}
```

My problem is in the line

```
    NSInteger number = useSecondView.numberOfImagesUploaded ;
```

While the number always return 0, as I test the contents of numberOfImagesUploaded in SecondViewController, it is a integer that is not zero. So, am my method wrongly to get a variable from other viewController? Or I cant access the variable which is inside a method body from another viewController?

Comment: NSInteger is a primitive type, so you dont need the * infront of `*number`

Comment: try to read warning from the compiler, it often helps

Comment: Thanks @Fonix , the yellow error is out. But the content of number is also 0. I tested in the SecondViewController, it's 2 ... Why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place `numberOfImagesUploaded = 1;` in your init method like so

```
//SecondViewController
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization

        numberOfImagesUploaded = 1; //make sure you are using the synthesized propert
    }
    return self;
}
```

edit:
just so you know in the future, this:

```
@synthesize numberOfImagesUploaded ;

NSInteger numberOfImagesUploaded = 1 ;
```

is wrong, you are redefining a variable here (not even sure why this would compile, local declaration probably hides the property defined in the header), but you already defined that variable in your header. if you want to give it a default value, either assign it in your init method, or do it in a `- viewDidLoad` or `- viewDidAppear` or something

edit 2:

remove the @property in the header and the @synthesize variables

in your implementation just have

```
static NSInteger numberOfImagesUploaded = 1 ; //sort of like you had it
```

define a method in your header

```
-(NSInteger)getNumberOfImagesUploaded;
```

then in your .m go

```
-(NSInteger)getNumberOfImagesUploaded {

     return numberOfImagesUploaded;
}
```

use this method in your thirdViewController to get the value of `numberOfImagesUploaded`

Comment: this will not work because if you set numberOfImagesUploaded = 1 ; then you will get every time 1 where he want updated value .

Comment: he has a method `-(IBAction)UploadMethod:(id)sender` that updates it. unless he wants it persistent between all `SecondViewControllers` then he can just make the variable static

Comment: I have another problem now, i tested the numberOfImagesUploaded inside the methid -(IBAction)UploadMethod:(id)sender, the content is 0 at the first call

Comment: But you have set this to 1 explicitly then it will not take the updated value

Comment: It should starts from 1, isn't it ?

Comment: And as @V-Xtreme said, the contents of number in thirdViewController is always 1 now... It won't update

Comment: it will be reset to 1 each time that view controller is made, if you want it to persist, then you would want to make `numberOfImagesUploaded` a static variable, and then have a function that will return that value to you. or you can try one of the ways V-Xtreme mentioned

Comment: I tried the method you edited, and I initialize the variable on viewDidLoad. But I still cannot get the correct value in ThirdViewController, why?

Comment: the viewDidLoad only gets called if you segue to the view (and the view loads) which wont happen yet if you just init the viewcontroller like you are doing in the code, ill update my answer to show you about the static variable.

Comment: It finally works with no error!! I really really thanks for your kindly help @Fonix

Answer (score 0):

if you want the numberOfImagesUploaded to be access into the secondViewController then there are several way :

1. You can send that variable to the custom init method like:

   `initWithnumberOfImagesUploaded:(int)num;`
2. You can use the appDelegate class . where you can declare that as a property and it will shared throughout the application but somewhere I have read that it is not the pure way .
3. Probably the pure way is to use Sigleton class. then you can preserve the state of that variable through out your application .

Comment: Thanks for the reply first @V-Xtreme. If I want to use the method 1, where should I insert initWithnumberOfImagesUploaded:(int)num; method? Second view or third view ?

Comment: I think its in your SecondViewController and you want to access that variable into the thirdControlled.